# Iron Python Twisted

Tags: ironpython, twisted

Is there an Iron Python .net port of the twisted libraries, or can Iron Python use the standard one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twisted will not currently run in IronPython, but it is being [worked on](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3882).

Stay tuned.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it myself, but you may get some mileage out of [Ironclad](http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/index.php/Ironclad.html) - it supposedly lets you use CPython from IronPython...