# Does IronPython implement python standard library?

Tags: python, ironpython

I tried IronPython some time ago and it seemed that it implements only python language, and uses .NET for libraries. Is this still the case? Can one use python modules from IronPython?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [IronPython installer](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22981) includes the Python standard library. Otherwise, you can use the standard library from a compatible Python install (IPy 2.0 -> CPy 2.5, IPy 2.6 -> CPy 2.6). Either copy the Python Lib directory to the IronPython folder, or set IRONPYTHONPATH.

Do note that only the pure Pyton modules will be available; Python modules that require C extensions have to be re-implemented (and most of them have been).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Python standard library from IronPython just fine. Here's how:

1. Install Python.
2. Setup an environment variable named IRONPYTHONPATH that points to the standard library directory.

Next time ipy.exe is run, site.py is read and you're good to go.

Comment: IRONPYTHONPATH is always searched, so you don't need to add it to site.py.

Comment: You just ended hours of headache for me.

Answer (score 3):

The .msi installer for [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com) includes all parts of the [CPython](http://python.org) standard library that should work with IronPython.  You can simply copy the standard library from a CPython install if you prefer, although you're better off getting just the modules that the IronPython developers have ensured with with IronPython - this is most of them.

Modules that are implemented using the CPython C API ('extension modules') will not be available.  [IronClad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) is an open-source project that aims to let you seamlessly use these modules - it's not perfect yet, but (e.g.) most of the NumPy tests pass.

The other option for these 'extension modules' is to replace them with a pure-Python version (e.g. from [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/)) or with a wrapper over a .NET class.  The [IronPython Community Edition](http://fepy.sourceforge.net/) is an IronPython distribution that includes such wrappers for many modules that are not included in the standard IronPython distribution.

Answer (score 0):

(As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676681/iron-python-twisted/677154#677154):)

> I've not used it myself, but you may
>   get some mileage out of [Ironclad](http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/index.php/Ironclad.html)
>   - it supposedly lets you use CPython from IronPython...

Comment: It depends purely on the needs. Its neat, but if you are going to use Python's standard lib, why use IronPython? (I know, I know, there could be valid reasons.)

Comment: For one, IronPython is by far the fastest Python implementation out there, at least in terms of throughput.