# .net framework with scrapy python

Tags: c#, python, scrapy, ironpython

Is it possible to use .NET framework with the Python [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework to scrape data from different sites?
I am working on my final year project in which I want to use C# as front end language and Python for scraping the data.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/3964225/2382792

Comment: I am interested in this too. Can I use scrapy from .net?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible, because Scrapy uses twisted networking engine which [can not run on IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676681/iron-python-twisted)

Alternatively, you may start your spider/crawler through command line using C# and then interact with it using [JSON API](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ScrapySharp](https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home), also described on [this blog](https://jfaquinojr.wordpress.com/2017/04/07/scrapysharp-c-web-scraping-library/), which is the C# version of python's Scrapy.